# Parse formdata from volley http response android

Tags: android, http, android-volley, httpresponse, form-data

I am getting formdata from http response in android. Please let me know the way to get post data from formdata. Following is the response received from http URL request (Volley has been used for http request):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <title>
            </title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form method="post" action="./MainData" id="form1">
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="j/1Pv8624GmE/EN9QpGcbC72eecrLPTDabltJNpGikgERxgV8/BH4rRxxI/u1+oI3d7LjNl97utqCCli7dGDtvCg2GbRAuQYHV8rDsxYqt8=" />
            <div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here, the post data in the form is encoded. Please let me know the way to parse the response to get the post data.

Thanks,

Comment: What is post data?

Comment: Post data could be any string that we can receive at the client side.

Comment: You gave no answer .

Comment: Here, value for form is "j/1Pv8624GmE/EN9QpGcbC72eecrLPTDabltJNpGikgERxgV8/BH4rRxxI/u1+oI3d7LjNl97utqCCli7dGDtvCg2GbRAuQYHV8rDsxYqt8=". Is there a way to get the decoded value from formdata?

Comment: Easy with a little bit of string manupulation. Use String.indexOf() and String.substring(). Undecoded.